# Is there any way to revive a dead on arrival new old stock MacBook battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I recently bought a boxed old stock genuine Apple A1185 battery for my MacBook. The battery appeared new but had clearly been in storage for many years and was not detected properly by my MacBook when installed and appears to be dead. The seller has already refunded but before I take it to recycling, is there anything I can try to revive it so it will take a charge?

Comment: Trying to jump-start a completely flat Li-Ion battery is a job for a professional.

Answer (score 2):

The A1185 battery is for 2006 to 2009 MacBooks. Apple has not held stock of these beyond 2016; and they would have been manufactured some years before that.

Even if never used, batteries have a limited life, and there's nothing you can do to 'revive' it, without risking fire.

Apple rarely sells parts to the public, and there is a large counterfeit market, so the genuine-ness of the product remains questionable, even if it's got "Apple" written on it.

Comment: Fair enough, it was cheap and boxed in Apple packaging. Seller refunded without quibbling so no loss. I was just trying to find out if resurrection was possible without anything too risky.

Comment: RE: "Apple never sells parts to the public" --  As I consider a replacement battery for my 2006 MBP a **part** and having purchased 2 of them over the years directly from **Apple** at their **Apple Retail Stores**, the quoted portion of your statement is false! Furthermore **Apple** is starting the  **Apple Self Service Repair Online Store** available to the general public, and will be available early next year, thus further making your statement false!

Comment: @user3439894 Well, obviously, I'm not talking about what Apple plans to do in the future, for a 2009 MB, so we can forget about that.

Comment: @user3439894 do you mean Apple sold you an installed battery (replacing yours), or an uninstalled part? Because CNBC has articles about how Apple doesn't sell batteries to customers "but it does not sell authentic batteries directly to users." https://www.cnbc.com/2019/08/18/apple-battery-fires-are-brand-risk.html and that's been my experience too. They don't sell parts like batteries that they don't think of as user installable directly to consumers.

Comment: @Todd Dabney, Over the years I have twice walked into an **Apple Retail Store** as a **retail customer**  and purchased a genuine **Apple** replacement battery for my 2006 **MacBook Pro** as an individually packaged **part** for replacement by the consumer where one removes the old battery and puts in the new battery in and is the primary reason I made the comment that "Apple never sells parts to the public" was false. People should refrain from maying absolute statements unless they know for a fact the statement being made is valid.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding. The a1185 battery was a user installable external battery that could be fitted without dismantling the MacBook. Apple later moved the battery inside so they were no longer like this. My dead battery is in Apple consumer packaging and was clearly sold direct to a customer at some point.

Comment: @user3439894 the key part you missed in what I wrote was "they don't think of as user installable directly to consumers". As Simon so helpfully pointed out the battery you're talking about was removable, and Apple hasn't shipped a laptop with one of those in over a decade. Apple has always sold a very small subset of parts it deemed user-installable (RAM, external batteries, etc) but internal components like an A1185 they have not sold in the past, though it sounds like they're going to start.